# python subclass autofilling parent method signature in IDE

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm not sure if there is a technical term to describe when an IDE auto-shows the method (or function) parameters as you start typing the method, in order to assist you in knowing what parameters you might need to fill in.

I am trying to preserve this type of behavior when I create a python subclass, but now when I type in the Pycharm IDE, the parameters show up as `self: Bar, *args, **kwargs` rather than `self: Bar, param_1, param2`

My original class was:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, param_1, param2):
        self.param_1 = param_1
        self.param_2 = param_2


class Bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this something specific to Pycharm, or is there some kind of functools magic I can use to keep the method signature of the parent, or do I have to explicitly write in all the parent parameters in the subclass?

Answer (score 1):

It's an IDE feature, not `functools` module. What you do is not really a subclassing, do it in this way:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

In that case you'll get `self: Bar, param_1, param2` on typing `Bar(`.

Comment: If I want to extend the class however, I won't be able to see the signature on the parent unless I explicitly specify all the parameters?

Comment: Can you provide some example? I don't get well what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want quickly override `__init__` method, type `class Bar(Foo):`, than use `Code->Override methods` functionality to generate boilerplate.

Comment: For example, I want to add a new argument into the class Bar but not have to retype all of the old arguments from the superclass: `class Bar:
    def __init__(self, new_arg, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Worth to mention your code will throw an error at runtime with `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. Let's imagine you mean `super(Bar, self)` and Bar inherited from `Foo`. I believe you should edit your code manually. Why IDE should know this `new_arg` will be used in `Bar.__init__` only or should be passed to `Foo.__init__` too?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I forgot to add (foo) to the class signature.